# How to use element from defs inside a circle in D3.JS

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have a shape (a drawn cloud) in a `g` within a `defs` tag. Unfortunately, I am not able to use this shape inside a `circle` using d3.js. Here is my code: 
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mojavascript/xLLa4q6g/)

What I am trying to do is to display that shape which is in defs tag inside the circle shown in the SVG. I have tried many times in different ways but I could not use the shape from the `defs` tag inside the `circle`. Could anyone please assist me with this issue? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `circle` can't contain other shapes. According to the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/circle) it may only contain [descriptive elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element#Descriptive) and [animation elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element#Animation_elements). These categories don't include shapes like `circle`, or `use`.

Rather than nesting your shapes, you should create a parent `g` and append the `circle` and `use` to that:

```
// Create a `g`, rather than a `circle`, for each data point
var groups = svg.selectAll(".group").data(data).enter().append("g")
                 .attr("class", "group");

// Append a `circle` to the new g
groups.append("circle")
                 .attr("cx",100).attr("cy",100).attr("r",20);

// Append a `use` to the new g
groups.append("use").attr("xlink:href", "#mySymbol");
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xLLa4q6g/3/#run)

Comment: Joews. Thank you very much for your reply. May you please explain to me in a few words about the class wrapper that you have used in your example. You have appended a circle to the variable circles that returns wrapper elements? Once again, thank you for your assistance.

Comment: I've added some comments and tidied up the variable names in the fiddle to make it clearer. Does that help?

Comment: I have read the comments. They help a lot. Thank you very much for your help, Joews.